# Could someone please explain why the alert is 1?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, alert

I'm new to js and am struggling to understand what is going on. I'm unsure what the `[v2[3]]` does and why the alert is `1`.

```
var v1=[5,4,3,2,1]; 
v2=[1,2,3,4,5];
alert(v1[v2[3]]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`v2[3]` is the 3rd element of array `v2`, equal to 4 (counting from index 0). And the 4th element in array `v1` is 1 (again counting from 0). Thus, `v1[v2[3]]` equals 1.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to look it this way

```
var v1=[5,4,3,2,1],
    v2=[1,2,3,4,5];

m = v2[3];//which is 4
alert(v1[m])//which is v1[4], so it's "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Always try to reduce the complexity when not sure what is going on

```js
var v1=[5,4,3,2,1]; 
v2=[1,2,3,4,5];

alert(v1[v2[3]]);//
//you can think like this
var index=v2[3];//you are getting array v2 value at index 3 
var actual_value=v1[index];//you are getting value of v1 based on index fetched from v2 
alert(index);//4
alert(actual_value)//1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the value of `v2[3]=4` and hence `alert(v1[v2[3]])` is same as `alert(v1[4]);`
as `v1[4]=1` the answer is 1.